# RED Robot Editor - One TestCase Dependent To Other

Tags: robotframework

I would like to set up things like if my login fails, skip the entire test cases. Or if TestCase11 is depending on TestCase9, then skip TestCase11 when TestCase9 fails.

I Went through the RED Editor if any such features, but my search didnt give me any solution. Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: There is no such function to provide additional logic for robot execution in RED and, honestly, should not be. You can control which suites/testcases are executed by launching selected testcases/files or using tags (this is done by Robot arguments) but logic regarding test dependency or launching order should be included only in tests itself thus being independent from any editor.

Comment: Thanks @jozefow ! I will try to find other solution like you said.